# Find the general solution to the ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$y′′+5y′+6y=85 e^{6x}\cos2x$

What is the general solution to this?

I got..

$y(x)=Ae^{−2x}+Be^{−3x}$

then doing it again i got a different answer.

$y(x)=Ae^{−x}+Be^{−2x}+86e^{2x}\sin3x$

What is the correct answer if it is either of these if not what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**: The particular solution $A_p = Me^{6x}\cos (2x) + Ne^{6x}\sin (2x)$. Can you plug it into the ODE and solve for $M,N$? And the general solution is: $A_g = A_h + A_p = Ae^{-2x}+ Be^{-3x} + Me^{6x}\cos (2x) + Ne^{6x}\sin (2x)$.

Comment: im looking for a general solution i think

Comment: Could that be simplified to $Ae^{−2x}+Be^{−3x}+e^{6x}*(cos2x+1/2sin2x)$

Comment: Yes, but the other form looks better.